# Do the given sentences convey what the speaker is looking to convey?

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage

Suppose someone's tests have been going on for a while, and the last test they had to take was earlier today. And you didn't know their tests were going on.

To convey that I could probably use a sentence like **"I had no idea your tests were going on, and that they got over today."** Correct me if i'm wrong here.

But, if i used a sentence like **"I had no idea your tests were going on until today."**,would it still mean the same, or would that mean that I got to know her tests were going on today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentences are not quite correct, from your description you only found out that the test ended earlier in the day either on the day or later.  You knew there were tests, but don't know when they were over.

> I had no idea your tests were going on, and that they got over today.

might be better expressed as

> I had no idea your tests were ***still*** going *( on )*, and that they *( only )* *( just )* ***finished*** today.

In your second example

> I had no idea your tests were going on until today.

is understandable, alternatives might be

> I had no idea your tests were *still* going until today.
>   I had no idea you *still had* tests *( until )* today.

Another permutation is

> I had no idea you had tests going on until today.

but is slightly ambiguous since it's not known if "today" refers to your "had no idea" or "tests ... until today".

Answer (score 1):

From

> I had no idea your tests were going on, and that they got over today.

we know two things, you didn't know about the tests, and the tests ended today. We don't know when you knew what.

But in

> I had no idea (your tests were going on) until today.

you are really saying

> I had no idea until today.

If you didn't know, it really doesn't matter what that was, so it is just saying you found out about the tests today.